# Overlay WAV files in C#

Tags: c#, audio, wav, mixing

How do I overlay two or more wav files in c# ?

Comment: Do you want to know how to play 2 wav files at a same time or to merge 2 wav files into 1?

Comment: na i wanted to mix them as its given here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CSharpWAVClassAndMixing.aspx , as in overlay , as in , its done .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Overlay? Mix them together? And output to soundcard? File? [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is handy for this kind of thing.